# Can anyone help me figure out how to do this Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this website http://www.montere.it/?lang=en and I love how they use the Javascript on their website. When you scroll down, the image will slightly appear and flip. I have tried so hard to find the sample online but none of them are like this. Or at least can anyone give me the website that has the Javascript collection.

Appreciate for all your help.

Comment: it is most probably flash

Comment: there is no flash on this page, just CSS3 transitions. Also what have you tried so far??

Comment: David Walsh has a pretty good blog post on developing this behavior with CSS - http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Comment: don't you have google?

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I myself is a designer and try to learn coding. Sorry again if the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I ripped the CSS animation code straight out of their page

```
@keyframes flipInY {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(20deg);
        -ms-transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(20deg);
        transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(20deg);
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
        transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
        opacity:1
    }
}
.flipInY {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:visible !important;
    -ms-backface-visibility:visible !important;
    backface-visibility:visible !important;
    -webkit-animation-name:flipInY;
    animation-name:flipInY
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration:.7s;
    animation-duration:.7s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both
}
```

**Run JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4of7L5aL/4/**

Basically when the user scrolls, you add the `animated` class to the element.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I am new for coding, sorry if the question doesn't make sense.